How to exit loop when encounter first integer in string
This is some code.
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage｛xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\xloop#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1
    \else

     **\IFInteger{#1}{first integer is here.}** % need to be modified

      \expandafter\xloop% 
  \fi}

\def\test#1{\xloop#1\relax}

\test{abc3de5f｝

\end{document}


On the original question of how to terminate your loop:
In case of your \xloop you have a terminating \relax. Provided that your input never contains a \relax token (which is already a prerequisite of your own loop) you can simply terminate your loop by swallowing everything up to that \relax, you just have to pay attention, since you're swallowing a \fi in the process you'll need to reinsert one. The following does that (but is then equivalent to the, imho, more clean expl3 based solution of my other answer):
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}

\begin{document}

\def\xloop#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \else
     \IfInteger{#1}{\xloopDone}{}%
      \expandafter\xloop
  \fi}
\def\xloopDone#1\relax{\fi first integer was here}

\def\test#1{\xloop#1\relax}

\test{abc3de5f}

\end{document}

Yields first integer was here and nothing else.

This answer relies on the fact that the digits 0-9 fall sequentially on the ASCII chart between slots 48 and 57, inclusive. The slot just prior to 0 contains / and the slot following 9 contains :.

We make use of TeX syntax that a grave accent (backtick) prior to a symbol produces the slot number (ASCII value) for the symbol.  So I set up two \ifnum tests...the first looks to see if the slot of the current symbol is beyond the slot of /, and the second test checks if the slot of the current symbol is prior to the slot of :.
If both these conditions are true, the slot of the symbol falls in the range of the integer slots.  Otherwise, it falls outside that range.
\documentclass{article}

\def\xloop#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1
    \else
%
      \ifnum`#1>`/ 
        \ifnum`#1<`:
           \def\next{#1 is first integer\\}%
        \else
          \def\next{#1 is not an integer\\\expandafter\xloop}
        \fi
      \else
        \def\next{#1 is not an integer\\\expandafter\xloop}
      \fi
      \next% 
  \fi}

\def\test#1{\xloop#1\relax}
\begin{document}
\test{abc3de5f}
\end{document}


Skillmon suggests a faster alternative which, as he notes, is equally robust.  In this case the comparison 1<1\noexpand#1 will prove false, unless #1 is a numerical digit.
\documentclass{article}

\def\xloop#1{%
  \ifx\relax#1
    \else
%
      \ifnum1<1\noexpand#1 
         \def\next{#1 is first integer\\}%
      \else
        \def\next{#1 is not an integer\\\expandafter\xloop}
      \fi
      \next% 
  \fi}

\def\test#1{\xloop#1\relax}
\begin{document}
\test{abc3de5f}
\end{document}


could you explain a little bit what this does?

this can check if a variable name contain number.

@XCN I have added explanation, per the request of cfr.

Though your test is robust, it is considerably slower than the equally robust check using \ifnum1<1\noexpand#1.

Here is an expandable solution using TeX primitives only:
\def\xloop#1{%
   \ifx\relax#1\else
      \ifnum 2<1#1 \loopE \else non-integer:#1 \fi
      \expandafter \xloop
   \fi
}
\def\loopE #1\relax{\fi\fi}

\xloop abc3de0f\relax

\bye

The test if #1 is an integer is done by \ifnum. There are two situations:
\ifnum 2<1x \loopE \else non-integer:x\fi

this test is false because 2<1 is not true. The else-text is procesed.
\ifnum 2<10 \loopE \else non-integer:0\fi

this test is true because 2<10 (or 11, or 12, etc.) is true. The macro \loopE does final work: ignores the next text to \relax and closes two opened \if branches.

Why just doing only digits?
Here \defineclass provides a form of \str_case:nnF, so the current item in the loop can be tested for being in the class or not.
With \loopbreak you can stop the loop. See the last examples.
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\stringloop}{mmmmm}
 {% #1 = string to test
  % #2 = class name (CN)
  % #3 = what to do if the item is in the class (YES)
  % #4 = what to do if the item is not in the class (NO}
  % #5 = what to do at the end if not stopped (END)
  \xcn_stringloop:ennnn {\tl_to_str:n {#1}} {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5}
 }

\cs_new:Nn \xcn_stringloop:nnnnn
 {
  \__xcn_stringloop:w {#2} {#3} {#4} {#5} #1 \q_nil
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \xcn_stringloop:nnnnn {e}

\cs_new:Npn \__xcn_stringloop:w #1 #2 #3 #4 #5
 {% #1 = CN, #2 = YES, #3 = NO, #4 = END, #5 = current item in string
  \quark_if_nil:nTF {#5}
   {
    #4
   }
   {
    \__xcn_stringloop_item:nnnnn {#1} {#5} {#2} {#3} {#4}
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__xcn_stringloop_item:nnnnn
 {% #1 = CN, #2 = current item in string, #3 = YES, #4 = NO, #5 = END
  \use:c {__xcn_stringloop_class_#1:nTF} {#2} {#3} {#4}
  \__xcn_stringloop:w {#1} {#3} {#4} {#5}
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineclass}{mm}
 {% #1 = class name, #2 = members
  \cs_new:ce {__xcn_stringloop_class_#1:nTF}
   {
    \exp_not:N \str_case:nnF {##1}
     { \tl_map_function:nN {#2} \__xcn_stringloop_make_case:n }
     { ##3 }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__xcn_stringloop_make_case:n { {#1}{##2} }

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\loopbreak}{m}
 {
  #1 \__xcn_stringloop_break:w
 }
\cs_new:Npn \__xcn_stringloop_break:w #1 \q_nil {}

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\checkforTF}{mmmm}
 {
  \xcn_stringloop:ennnn {\tl_to_str:n {#1}} {#2} {\loopbreak{#3}} {} {#4}  
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\defineclass{digits}{0123456789}
\defineclass{unknowns}{xyz}

\begin{document}

\raggedright

\stringloop{abc3def5g}{digits}{DIGIT }{NONDIGIT }{END}

\bigskip

\stringloop{abc3def5g}{digits}{\loopbreak{DIGIT, STOP}}{NONDIGIT }{END}

\bigskip

\checkforTF{abc3def5g}{digits}{There's a digit}{There's no digit}

\bigskip

\checkforTF{abcdefg}{digits}{There's a digit}{There's no digit}

\bigskip

\edef\test{\checkforTF{abc3def5g}{digits}{There's a digit}{There's no digit}}
\texttt{\meaning\test}

\bigskip

\stringloop{abxcy}{unknowns}{(unknown)}{(parameter)}{}

\bigskip

\stringloop{abxc}{unknowns}{\loopbreak{(unknown)}}{(parameter)}{end}

\bigskip

\stringloop{abc}{unknowns}{\loopbreak{(unknown)}}{(parameter)}{end}

\end{document}



If this is only about checking whether there was a number contained, the following is a rather fast approach for that:
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand\ifcontainsnum{mmm}
  { \xcn_if_contains_num:nTF {#1} {#2} {#3} }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \xcn_if_contains_num:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  {
    \str_map_function:nN {#1} \__xcn_if_contains_num:n
    \prg_return_false:
  }
\cs_new:Npn \__xcn_if_contains_num:n #1
  { \xcn_if_digit:nT {#1} { \str_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } } }
\prg_new_conditional:Npnn \xcn_if_digit:n #1 { TF, T, F, p }
  {
    \if_int_compare:w 1 < 1\exp_not:N#1 \exp_stop_f:
      \prg_return_true:
    \else:
      \prg_return_false:
    \fi:
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ifcontainsnum{abc}{yes}{no}

\ifcontainsnum{abc1}{yes}{no}

\ifcontainsnum{ab{c1}}{yes}{no}
\end{document}

This yields no, yes, and yes.
